# Hexadecimal characters

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to check the strings are hexadecimal or not.  The below code works fine.

```
   [0-9A-F]+
```

In some cases, There will be character 'X' inbetween like,

1234X3D

X12353D

1234E3X

Can someone help me in changing this regex?

Comment: `X` isn't a hex character in my book…

Comment: yeah, i tried.  Only in some cases the character 'X' appears.  So it should be an optional

Comment: If you're trying to check if they're hexadecimal, and that fails ... they're not hexadecimal. It appears you're really trying to do something else. The first comment tells you how to add `X` to the set

Comment: X is not hex character.  Along with the hexadecimal, in some strings, the character X appears

Comment: "*In some cases, There will be character 'X' inbetween like, `1234X3D` `X12353D` `1234E3X`*" And? Is it good? Is it bad? What are you trying to achieve? Could you provide some example of input and expected output?

Comment: i got it, ([0-9A-F]+)|([0-9A-FX]+) does it

Comment: That is functionally identical to my comment above, just needlessly more complicated...

Comment: @FirmView: as mentioned by @femtoRgon, `[0-9A-FX]` should do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Without questioning why you want to think of X as a hexidecimal digit,  The correct answer to your question is:

```
[0-9A-FX]+
```

Nowhere does that regex require an 'X' to be present.
While this is acceptable, as well:

```
 ([0-9A-F]+)|([0-9A-FX]+)
```

It is needlessly complicated, and redundant.  This is because [0-9A-F]+ is a subset of [0-9A-FX]+.  Consider the DFA created here:

DFA1: [0-9A-F]+

```
Accepting: state 1
State 0      input: 0-9A-F             to state 1
State 1      input: 0-9A-F             to state 1
```

DFA2: [0-9A-FX]+

```
Accepting: state 1
State 0      input: 0-9A-F             to state 1
State 0      input: X                  to state 1
State 1      input: 0-9A-F             to state 1
State 1      input: X                  to state 1
```

Note, that all accepting state transitions present in DFA1 are also present in DFA2.  Therefore the matched inputs of DFA1 ([0-9A-F]+) are a subset of DFA2 ([0-9A-FX]+)

Or, more concisely:

([0-9A-F]+) ⊆ ([0-9A-FX]+)

And if A ⊆ B then A|B=B

Therefore ([0-9A-F]+)|([0-9A-FX]+) = [0-9A-FX]+.

QED